# Verb that means to convert an enum to its string representation?

Tags: enums, naming

What verb means to convert an enum from its numerical representation to its string representation?

ie. to name a function which takes 0, 1 or 2 as input and returns dogs, cats or rabbits.

Comment: that broadly covers it, but was hoping for something more specific. I've just seen 'Parse' is used for this action currently in our codebase but not sure how I feel about that.

Comment: my advice: if you're not sure, better not tell them how you feel until you are sure, otherwise you're like playing with their feelings

Comment: @testpattern, I'm onto you Calder.

Comment: I wonder how long until this gets closed as not constructive